# Boost "is_virtual_base_of" compile error when migrating working module

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have been working with boost serialization, I developed a whole module to store classes in persistent storage, but when I try to migrate my module to other project I got some errors I have never seen and I don't found any related information on the net.

The error I get is:

```
In file included from support.../boost_1_44/boost/serialization/void_cast.hpp:29,
                 from support.../boost_1_44/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:57,
                 from support.../boost_1_44/boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp:23,
                 from support.../boost_1_44/boost/archive/detail/common_oarchive.hpp:22,
                 from support.../boost_1_44/boost/archive/basic_binary_oarchive.hpp:34,
                 from support.../boost_1_44/boost/archive/binary_oarchive_impl.hpp:23,
                 from support.../boost_1_44/boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp:21,
                 from .../ps_proxy.h:54,

support.../boost_1_44/boost/type_traits/is_virtual_base_of.hpp:57:10: error: macro "X" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
support.../boost_1_44/boost/type_traits/is_virtual_base_of.hpp:58:18: error: macro "X" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
support.../boost_1_44/boost/type_traits/is_virtual_base_of.hpp:60:11: error: macro "X" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
support.../boost_1_44/boost/type_traits/is_virtual_base_of.hpp:57: error: declaration does not declare anything
support.../boost_1_44/boost/type_traits/is_virtual_base_of.hpp:58: error: declaration does not declare anything
support.../boost_1_44/boost/type_traits/is_virtual_base_of.hpp:60: error: declaration of '~boost::detail::is_virtual_base_of_impl<Base, Derived, mpl_::bool_<true> >::X' as non-function
support.../boost_1_44/boost/type_traits/is_virtual_base_of.hpp:60: error: expected ';' before 'throw'
```

I hope someone can give me some tip regarding why this could happend and why it works correctly on one module and when i migrate it (supposed to be transparent migration) it throws these erros.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `boost::is_virtual_base_of<>` is used somewhere in the implementation of Boost.Serialization.
2. In Boost 1.44, `boost::is_virtual_base_of<>` used types named `X` and `Y` as implementation details.
3. Somewhere in your other project there is a macro named `X` defined, breaking the `X` type used in the implementation of `boost::is_virtual_base_of<>`.

Clearly `X` is a terrible macro name -- if it's yours then find a better name, and if it's not then email the author of whatever library did define it and complain (then `#undef` it before including any Boost headers).

FWIW, this was apparently a common enough issue that in Boost 1.47 types named `boost_type_traits_internal_struct_X` and `boost_type_traits_internal_struct_Y` are used instead of `X` and `Y`, so upgrading to a more current version of Boost is another way to work around your symptom.

Comment: Thanks! That was te issue I'll complain with the author of that macro :P. Now I can integrate my module :-)